# AWS free tier EC2 EBS snapshot billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working on a small personal project with a free-tier account.

I have one linux instance which I have my nodejs app running. The app basically listens for any incoming websocket data and uses AWS SNS to send the data to my iPhone. App needs to access RDS DB that I set up every time this happens.

Today I got an email saying that I used 85% of the usage limit for AWS EBS snapshot storage. I left it for few hours and now it used 100% and it says the Month-end forecasted usage is 3 GB-mo 310.00%.

It seems like this EBS snapshot is just a backup so is there a way to disable this to keep my cost $0? If not, how much will it cost me to run this app? Would moving the RDS DB to ec2 help reduce some cost?

Comment: If you go to the **Snapshots** section in the Amazon EC2 management console, are any snapshots listed? Have you created any AMIs? Amazon EBS snapshots are only charged at 5c/GB/Month.

Comment: I think I tried to move server and created them. I removed snapshots and AMI just now. Will this solve my issue?

Comment: The cost of snapshots is based on the Snapshots you have in your account. AMIs are also snapshots, with additional metadata. So, if you have deleted them, there will be no more charges for snapshots.